# Error while mapping the data from CSV file to a Hive table on HDFS

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to load a dataframe into a Hive table by following the below steps:

1. Read the source table and save the dataframe as a CSV file on HDFS

   ```
   val yearDF = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", connectionUrl).option("dbtable", s"(${execQuery}) as year2016").option("user", devUserName).option("password", devPassword).option("partitionColumn","header_id").option("lowerBound", 199199).option("upperBound", 284058).option("numPartitions",10).load()
   ```
2. Order the columns as per my Hive table columns
   My hive table columns are present in a string in the format of:

   ```
   val hiveCols = col1:coldatatype|col2:coldatatype|col3:coldatatype|col4:coldatatype...col200:datatype
   val schemaList        = hiveCols.split("\\|")
   val hiveColumnOrder   = schemaList.map(e => e.split("\\:")).map(e => e(0)).toSeq
   val finalDF           = yearDF.selectExpr(hiveColumnOrder:_*)
   ```

   The order of columns that I read in "execQuery" are same as "hiveColumnOrder" and just to make sure of the order, I select the columns in yearDF once again using selectExpr
3. Saving the dataframe as a CSV file on HDFS:

   ```
   newDF.write.format("CSV").save("hdfs://username/apps/hive/warehouse/database.db/lines_test_data56/")
   ```
4. Once I save the dataframe, I take the same columns from "hiveCols",
   prepare a DDL to create a hive table on the same location with values being comma separated as given
   below:

> create table if not exists schema.tablename(col1 coldatatype,col2 
>   coldatatype,col3 coldatatype,col4 coldatatype...col200 datatype)
>   ROW
>   FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
>   STORED AS TEXTFILE
>
> LOCATION
>   'hdfs://username/apps/hive/warehouse/database.db/lines_test_data56/';

After I load the dataframe into the table created, the problem I am facing here is when I query the table, I am getting improper output in the query.
For ex: If I apply the below query on the dataframe before saving it as a file:

```
finalDF.createOrReplaceTempView("tmpTable")
select header_id,line_num,debit_rate,debit_rate_text,credit_rate,credit_rate_text,activity_amount,activity_amount_text,exchange_rate,exchange_rate_text,amount_cr,amount_cr_text from tmpTable where header_id=19924598 and line_num=2
```

I get the output properly. All the values are properly aligned to the columns:

```
[19924598,2,null,null,381761.40000000000000000000,381761.4,-381761.40000000000000000000,-381761.4,0.01489610000000000000,0.014896100000000,5686.76000000000000000000,5686.76]
```

But after saving the dataframe in a CSV file, create a table on top of it (step4) and apply the same query on the created table I see the data is jumbled and improperly mapped with the columns:

```
select header_id,line_num,debit_rate,debit_rate_text,credit_rate,credit_rate_text,activity_amount,activity_amount_text,exchange_rate,exchange_rate_text,amount_cr,amount_cr_text from schema.tablename where header_id=19924598 and line_num=2

+---------------+--------------+-------------+------------------+-------------+------------------+--------------------------+-------------------------------+------------------------+-----------------------------+--------------------+-------------------------+--+
| header_id     | line_num     | debit_rate  | debit_rate_text  | credit_rate  | credit_rate_text  | activity_amount  | activity_amount_text  | exchange_rate  | exchange_rate_text  | amount_cr  | amount_cr_text  |
+---------------+--------------+-------------+------------------+-------------+------------------+--------------------------+-------------------------------+------------------------+-----------------------------+--------------------+-------------------------+--+
| 19924598      | 2            | NULL        |                  | 381761.4    |                    | 5686.76          | 5686.76               | NULL           | -5686.76            | NULL       |                 |
```

So I tried use a different approach where I created the hive table upfront and insert data into it from dataframe:

- Running the DDL in step4 above
- finalDF.createOrReplaceTempView("tmpTable")
- spark.sql("insert into schema.table select * from tmpTable")

And even this way fails if I run the aforementioned select query once the job is completed.
I tried to refresh the table using `refresh table schema.table` and `msckrepair table schema.table` just to see if there is any problem with the metadata but nothing seems to workout.

Could anyone let me know what is causing this phenomenon, is there is any problem with the way I operating the data here ?

Comment: In summary, you have some CSV files and you want to create Hive tables from them and run query on them using JDBC tools like beeline?

Comment: Yes. I did create the table using Beeline. Any issue with that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the rowformat serde: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde in the Hive DDL. This also has ',' as default separator char and I didn't have to give any other delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

Codes are tested using **Spark 2.3.2**

---

Instead creating Spark dataframe from CSV file and then register it as Hive Table, you can easily run SQL commands and create Hive Tables from CSV file

```scala
val conf = new SparkConf
    conf
      .set("hive.server2.thrift.port", "10000")
      .set("spark.sql.hive.thriftServer.singleSession", "true")
      .set("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "hdfs://PATH_FOR_HIVE_METADATA")
      .set("spark.sql.catalogImplementation","hive")
      .setMaster("local[*]")
      .setAppName("ThriftServer")

val spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .config(conf)
      .enableHiveSupport()
      .getOrCreate()
```

Now using `spark` object you can run SQL command as Hive user:

```scala
spark.sql("DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS my_db CASCADE")
spark.sql("create database if not exists my_db")
spark.sql("use my_db")
```

Using the following code you can load all csv_files in an HDFS directory (or you can give the path of exactly one CSV file):

```scala
spark.sql(
      "CREATE TABLE test_table(" +
        "id int," +
        "time_stamp bigint," +
        "user_name string) " +
        "ROW FORMAT DELIMITED " +
        "FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' " +
        "STORED AS TEXTFILE " +
        "LOCATION 'hdfs://PATH_TO_CSV_Directory_OR_CSV_FILE' "
    )
```

And at the end register Spark *sqlContext* object as Hive ThriftServer:

```scala
HiveThriftServer2.startWithContext(spark.sqlContext)
```

This will create a ThriftServer endpoint on the port 10000.

```scala
INFO ThriftCLIService: Starting ThriftBinaryCLIService on port 10000 with 5...500 worker threads
```

Now you can run beeline and connect to the ThriftServer:

```scala
beeline> !connect jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000
Connecting to jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000
Enter username for jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000: enter optional_username
Enter password for jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000: leave blank
Connected to: Spark SQL (version 2.3.2)
Driver: Hive JDBC (version 1.2.1.spark2)
Transaction isolation: TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ
0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000>
```

And test if the table `test_table` is created under `my_db` database:

```scala
0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000> use my_db;
0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000> show tables ;
+-----------+-----------------------+--------------+--+
| database  |       tableName       | isTemporary  |
+-----------+-----------------------+--------------+--+
| my_db     | test_table            | false        |
+-----------+-----------------------+--------------+--+
```

Also, you can create any other Hive table (or any HiveQL command) using ThrifServer JDBC endpoint.

Here are the needed dependencies:

```scala
 libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive-thriftserver" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-hdfs" % "2.8.3",
  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-common" % "2.8.3",
)
```

Comment: Using Row format serde: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde solved my problem.